# How do you set up Filebeat on docker?

Tags: docker, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I am trying to set up Filebeat on Docker. The rest of the stack (Elastic, Logstash, Kibana) is already set up.

I want to forward syslog files from `/var/log/` to Logstash with Filebeat. I created a new *filebeat.yml* file on the host system under `/etc/filebeat/`(I created this filebeat directory, not sure if that's correct?):

```
output:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

filebeat:
  inputs:
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/syslog
        - /var/log/auth.log
      document_type: syslog
```

Then I ran the Filebeat container: `sudo docker run -v /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.4.2`
It is able to run, but no files are actually being forwarded to logstash. I am thinking the issue is with the *filebeat.yml* configuration...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Even if the config file lives on the host system, the process inside the container will interpret those config paths as being in the container space: you are forwarding logs from the _container's_ `/var/log`, not the host's.

Answer (score 0):

As David Maze intimated, the reason that filebeat isn't forwarding any logs is because it only has access to logs within the container.  You can share those logs using another bind mount.  My preferred option when using docker + filebeat is to have filebeat listen on a TCP/IP port and have the log source forward logs to that port.